# How do I (1) Create A Randomly Generated Email in Javascript (2) Auto fill a form with it

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

and thanks for taking time to at least pity my lack of knowledge.

I have a wordpress installation (stay with me..) that has a plugin where you enter some information including an email, in order to add, in this instance a new booking (crm type thing). This is done in the back end by admin. On some occasions, the client doesn't have an email address and as a hacky workaround i'd like the system to just generate a random email address in the box whenever it's left empty.

Much of the plugin is in Javascript and i think i've found the validation function where my snippet might need 'injecting':

(1)
I'm fairly comfortable with PHP, and have written something that generates a random email (which will only be used internally)

```
//Random email address generator
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
$randomString .= "@mysite.co.uk";
return $randomString;
```

}

(yes I know, there are a million neater ways to accomplish the above)

(2) I think i've found the bit of javascript that validates the email input and was just hoping this may be the chunk of code i'd need to look at in order to generate a random email, if nothing else was entered.

```
function sln_validateBooking() {
var $ = jQuery;
$('.sln-invalid').removeClass('sln-invalid');
$('.sln-error').remove();
var hasErrors = false;

var toValidate = [
    '#_sln_booking_service_select'
];

var fields = $('#salon-step-date').attr('data-required_user_fields').split(',');
$.each(fields, function(k, val) {
    toValidate.push('#_sln_booking_' + val);
});

$.each(toValidate, function (k, val) {
    if (val == '#_sln_booking_phone' && !$('[name=_sln_booking_createuser]').is(':checked')) {
        return;
    } else if (val == '#_sln_booking_email') {
        if (!$('[name=_sln_booking_createuser]').is(':checked') && !$(val).val()) {
            return;
        } else if (!sln_validateEmail($(val).val())) {
            $(val).addClass('sln-invalid').parent().append('<div class="sln-error error">This field is not a valid email</div>');
            if (!hasErrors) $(val).focus();
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    } else if (val == '#_sln_booking_service_select') {
        if (!$('[name=_sln_booking\\[services\\]\\[\\]]').size()) {
            $(val).addClass('sln-invalid').parent().append('<div class="sln-error error">This field is required</div>');
            if (!hasErrors) $(val).focus();
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    } else if (!$(val).val()) {
        $(val).addClass('sln-invalid').parent().append('<div class="sln-error error">This field is required</div>');
        if (!hasErrors) $(val).focus();
        hasErrors = true;
    }
});
return !hasErrors;
```

}

What would be great to know is a) if i should just shoot myself in the face and never go near a line of code again and also b) if there is a neat solution to this that I may forever be in your debt for solving.

UPDATE:
I've decided it would probably be better to pass this randomly generated email address to the empty field via a metabox, and not to hack at the plugin's code (which would only get overwritten)..

However.. I get 'uncaught referenceError : rand is not defined at HTMLinputelement.onclick for both functions if i do something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name" placeholder="click to generate" value="" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large" id="btn_Gen" 
onclick="rand();" value="Generate" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large" id="btn_Run" 
onclick="fn_copy();" value="Autofill" />
<br/>
<script>
function rand() {
document.getElementById("txt_name").value = generateRandStr();
}

function generateRandStr() {
var candidates = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY123456789";
var randomemail = "",
rand;
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * candidates.length);
randomemail += candidates.charAt(rand);
}
randomemail += "@blahblah.co.uk";
}
return randomemail;
}
//working    
function fn_copy() {
var temp = document.getElementById("txt_name").value;
if (temp != "") {
document.getElementById("_sln_booking_email").value = temp;
} else
alert("Text is Empty");
}
</script>
```

HELP!

Comment: Does the email address need to be unique? Can you just put in `no-email@example.com` for every booking instead?

Comment: needs to be unique i'm afraid.

Comment: Your code actually works well in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jLouyb3z/, I think it's something in your environment making `onclick=...` not work.  Should be able to attach click listeners without using that though

Comment: check out this updated fiddle, I attach listeners in the script https://jsfiddle.net/jLouyb3z/1/

Comment: if that doesn't work you might try putting them in window.onload like this https://jsfiddle.net/jLouyb3z/2/

Comment: Thanks - your second fiddle allows the 'fn_copy' to work properly, however the function 'rand' still throws the same error..

Comment: Actually.. that works PERFECTLY! Thank you

Comment: :boom: Awesome! good job, keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

After this line

`} else if (!sln_validateEmail($(val).val())) {`

remove all the code that notifies the user of invalid input and set the value to your random email.

```
    } else if (!sln_validateEmail($(val).val())) {
        $(val).val(Math.random().toString(36).substring(5) + "@mysite.co.uk")
    }
```

I'm not sure you want to lean on that `Math.random` call to make billions of unique emails but it might get you by.

Comment: you sir, are a star.

Comment: Could i modify this using yours and my solutions, to appear in a metabox on it's own and just pass the randomly generated email to the correct box?

Comment: @NHUD so are you basically trying to avoid letting the user see the random email string, and just pass it to the server without anyone seeing it?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with wordpress so I might not be able to help you with the specifics

Comment: The user can see the email sure. I've updated my post with a more concise version of what i'd like to achieve... any help appreciated.